# Animate stroke-width with Highcharts renderer

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts SVG rendering API (Renderer) to draw custom chart and I want to animate rect's stroke-width attribute. [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/element-on/) the example provided in Highcharts documentation, but it seems not working properly - all attributes are changed except stroke-width.
If I open HTML in Chrome DevTools I can see something like that:

```
<rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" stroke="gray"
stroke-width="2" fill="silver" zIndex="3" strokeWidth="10"></rect>
```

Stroke-width is set using camel-style name, not dash-style name.

May be there is some workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, there is a workaround. You can achieve this by using the attr() function of jQuery. When you click on the rectangle you change the stroke-width attribute.

Still I think this is a good point to report perhaps as a bug of the API?

Anyways the JS code will look like this:

```
$(function () {
    var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
            $('#container')[0],
            400,
            300
        ),
        rect = renderer.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 5)
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'gray',
                fill: 'silver',
                zIndex: 3
            })
            .on('click', function () {
                rect.animate({
                    x: 50,
                    y: 50,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 20
                })
                $("rect").attr("stroke-width", "30"); // here you can change the stroke-width               
            })
            .add();
});
```

To see it in action here the adjusted [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rjc3n52t/)

---

**VERSION 2**

Based on your comment I edit the code. In this case you set also an animation for the stroke-width. This is a simple solution. Another solution would be tweaking the original Highcharts library which I would not recommend. Anyways, hope it helps:

```
$(function () {
    var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
            $('#container')[0],
            400,
            300
        ),
        rect = renderer.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 5)
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'gray',
                fill: 'silver',
                zIndex: 3
            })
            .on('click', function () {
                rect.animate({
                    x: 50,
                    y: 50,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 20
                })
                $("rect").animate(
                    { "stroke-width": "10" },
                    {
                        duration: 500, 
                        step: function(now) { $(this).attr("stroke-width", now); }
                    });                
            })
            .add();
});
```

The duration can be adjusted to what is suitable for you. 
See it in action here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/emgnjnq5/)

Comment: Thanks, @Rotan075. Unfortunatelly this workaround do not animate stroke-width, it changes it at once.

Comment: @rebelraven You can also tweak that with jQuery. Perhaps not a smooth solution but it will come close to your preferences I guess. Look at my modified answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Rotan075. Second version looks like what I need. Still, I posted issue to Highcharts Github repo [link](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4721)

Comment: Yep, good one! Glad I could help creating some kind of workaround! ;) Hope they could solve this "bug" @rebelraven